# Rsync multiple folder sources using wildcard and filtering files using extension

Tags: file, filtering, rsync, directory

I'm trying to update recursively some *.png files from various folders. 
My goal is to do it in ONE command.

This works for the folder SQ002 :

```
rsync -r -v --size-only --chmod=ugo=rwX --include='SQ001/***' --include='*.png' --exclude='*' /LocalFolder/ root@distantServer:/distantFolder/
```

All *.png files from SQ002 subdirectories are copied.

But when I want to add a second folder...

```
rsync -r -v --size-only --chmod=ugo=rwX --include='SQ001/***' --include='SQ002/***' --include='*.png' --exclude='*' /LocalFolder/ root@distantServer:/distantFolder/
```

All the files are copied whatever the files extenstions are.

If someone can help me !!

Answer (score 0):

Both of your commands will include all files (eg. *.jpg also) - see the sample output at the end of this answer.

What you might want is something like this:
`rsync -m -r -v --size-only --chmod=ugo=rwX --exclude='/SQ00[3-9]' --include='*/' --include='*.png' --exclude='*' /LocalFolder/ root@distantServer:/distantFolder/`

The caveat is that you now have to exclude all folders that you don't want to update, as opposed to include those that you want to update, as before.
So the `--exclude='/SQ00[3-9]'` must be first, before the `--include='*/'` (which includes all directories and subdirectories of `/LocalFolder/`) in order for this to work.

I added '-m' to `-m, --prune-empty-dirs      prune empty directory chains from file-list` this will avoid empty dirs.

That's all, now let me show you how various variants look, below.

Let's set the stage by:
1. using `./srcdir/` in place of `/LocalFolder/`, `./destdir/` in place of `root@distantServer:/distantFolder/`
2. showing what we have inside `./srcdir/`:

```
$ find srcdir -printf '%P\n' | sort

SQ001
SQ001/1
SQ001/1/5
SQ001/1/5/one4.png
SQ001/1/7
SQ001/1/7/one5.png
SQ001/1/emptydir1
SQ001/1/one3.png
SQ001/1/somefile2.jpg
SQ001/emptydir4
SQ001/one2.png
SQ001/one.png
SQ001/somefile.jpg
SQ001/SQ003
SQ001/SQ003/one.png
SQ001/SQ003/somefile.jpg
SQ002
SQ002/1
SQ002/1/5
SQ002/1/5/one4.png
SQ002/1/5/somefile4.jpg
SQ002/1/7
SQ002/1/7/one5.png
SQ002/1/emptydir2
SQ002/1/one3.png
SQ002/1/somefile3.jpg
SQ002/emptydir5
SQ002/somefile2.jpg
SQ002/two2.png
SQ002/two.png
SQ003
SQ003/1
SQ003/1/5
SQ003/1/5/one4.png
SQ003/1/5/somefile4.jpg
SQ003/1/7
SQ003/1/7/one5.png
SQ003/1/emptydir3
SQ003/1/one3.png
SQ003/1/somefile3.jpg
SQ003/emptydir6
SQ003/one2.png
SQ003/somefile2.jpg
SQ003/three.png
SQ006
SQ006/one2.png
SQ006/somefile2.jpg
SQ009
SQ009/one2.png
SQ009/somefile2.jpg
```

jpg files are used in place of any other non-png file, to see if our rsync commands take anything other than png (which would be bad - not what we wanted)

Now let's see what happens with various rsync commands:

`$ rm -rf destdir; rsync -m -r -v --size-only --chmod=ugo=rwX --exclude='/SQ00[3-9]' --include='*/' --include='*.png' --exclude='*' ./srcdir/ ./destdir/`

```
building file list ... done
created directory ./destdir
./
SQ001/
SQ001/one.png
SQ001/one2.png
SQ001/1/
SQ001/1/one3.png
SQ001/1/5/
SQ001/1/5/one4.png
SQ001/1/7/
SQ001/1/7/one5.png
SQ001/SQ003/
SQ001/SQ003/one.png
SQ002/
SQ002/two.png
SQ002/two2.png
SQ002/1/
SQ002/1/one3.png
SQ002/1/5/
SQ002/1/5/one4.png
SQ002/1/7/
SQ002/1/7/one5.png

sent 1,075 bytes  received 287 bytes  2,724.00 bytes/sec
total size is 22  speedup is 0.02
```

So, all empty dirs are excluded (due to `-m`), only `*.png` files are updated (so others like `*.jpg` are ignored, as desired), the SQ003 subdir inside SQ001 is (correctly) NOT ignored, only the root SQ003 is (as per pattern `--exclude='/SQ00[3-9]'` whose `/` ensures that); SQ006 and SQ009 also match the exclusion pattern. So this is basically your answer, with the caveat that you have to exclude every other root folder (similar to SQ003, SQ006, SQ009) if you just want SQ001 and SQ002 to be updated.

Next, what happens if you don't use `-m`:
`$ rm -rf destdir; rsync -r -v --size-only --chmod=ugo=rwX --exclude='/SQ00[3-9]' --include='*/' --include='*.png' --exclude='*' ./srcdir/ ./destdir/`

```
sending incremental file list
created directory ./destdir
./
SQ001/
SQ001/one.png
SQ001/one2.png
SQ001/1/
SQ001/1/one3.png
SQ001/1/5/
SQ001/1/5/one4.png
SQ001/1/7/
SQ001/1/7/one5.png
SQ001/1/emptydir1/
SQ001/SQ003/
SQ001/SQ003/one.png
SQ001/emptydir4/
SQ002/
SQ002/two.png
SQ002/two2.png
SQ002/1/
SQ002/1/one3.png
SQ002/1/5/
SQ002/1/5/one4.png
SQ002/1/7/
SQ002/1/7/one5.png
SQ002/1/emptydir2/
SQ002/emptydir5/

sent 1,173 bytes  received 316 bytes  992.67 bytes/sec
total size is 23  speedup is 0.02
```

As you can see the emptydirs are in the list, so you get them at the destination (maybe this is desired, so up to you).

Now let's see what happens if you move the `--include='*/'` before the `--exclude='/SQ00[3-9]'`:
`$ rm -rf destdir; rsync -r -v --size-only --chmod=ugo=rwX  --include='*/' --exclude='/SQ00[3-9]' --include='*.png' --exclude='*' ./srcdir/ ./destdir/`

```
sending incremental file list
created directory ./destdir
./
SQ001/
SQ001/one.png
SQ001/one2.png
SQ001/1/
SQ001/1/one3.png
SQ001/1/5/
SQ001/1/5/one4.png
SQ001/1/7/
SQ001/1/7/one5.png
SQ001/1/emptydir1/
SQ001/SQ003/
SQ001/SQ003/one.png
SQ001/emptydir4/
SQ002/
SQ002/two.png
SQ002/two2.png
SQ002/1/
SQ002/1/one3.png
SQ002/1/5/
SQ002/1/5/one4.png
SQ002/1/7/
SQ002/1/7/one5.png
SQ002/1/emptydir2/
SQ002/emptydir5/
SQ003/
SQ003/one2.png
SQ003/three.png
SQ003/1/
SQ003/1/one3.png
SQ003/1/5/
SQ003/1/5/one4.png
SQ003/1/7/
SQ003/1/7/one5.png
SQ003/1/emptydir3/
SQ003/emptydir6/
SQ006/
SQ006/one2.png
SQ009/
SQ009/one2.png

sent 1,859 bytes  received 481 bytes  4,680.00 bytes/sec
total size is 37  speedup is 0.02
```

So it's as if it didn't exist.

This answer is getting kind of long, so I'll just include just one more variant, yours:
`$ rm -rf destdir; rsync -r -v --size-only --chmod=ugo=rwX --include='SQ00[1-2]/***' --include='*.png' --exclude='*' ./srcdir/ ./destdir/`

```
sending incremental file list
created directory ./destdir
./
SQ001/
SQ001/one.png
SQ001/one2.png
SQ001/somefile.jpg
SQ001/1/
SQ001/1/one3.png
SQ001/1/somefile2.jpg
SQ001/1/5/
SQ001/1/5/one4.png
SQ001/1/7/
SQ001/1/7/one5.png
SQ001/1/emptydir1/
SQ001/SQ003/
SQ001/SQ003/one.png
SQ001/SQ003/somefile.jpg
SQ001/emptydir4/
SQ002/
SQ002/somefile2.jpg
SQ002/two.png
SQ002/two2.png
SQ002/1/
SQ002/1/one3.png
SQ002/1/somefile3.jpg
SQ002/1/5/
SQ002/1/5/one4.png
SQ002/1/5/somefile4.jpg
SQ002/1/7/
SQ002/1/7/one5.png
SQ002/1/emptydir2/
SQ002/emptydir5/

sent 1,591 bytes  received 430 bytes  4,042.00 bytes/sec
total size is 35  speedup is 0.02
```

If you replace `SQ00[1-2]` with `SQ001` to get your first command, you get the same result except SQ002/ is not included, but as you can see even *.jpg are included.